Add an external plugin to RabbitMQ host in Azure
I'm trying to run a RabbitMQ host in Aspire 9 with rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange plugin installed.
I've downladed the plugin in a folder {curDir}/volumes/rabbitmq/plugins, and I've been activated through commands, and the container activate the plugin, but the container closes .
The code:
        var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        var curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var rabbitMQ = builder.AddRabbitMQ(nameof(CTE.enmMicroservicios.RabbitMQ))
            .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER", "guest")
            .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS", "guest")
            .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR", "/opt/rabbitmq/plugins:/myplugins")
            .WithManagementPlugin()
            .WithEndpoint("management", e => e.Port = 15674)
            .WithImageTag(tag: "3.13")
            .WithBindMount($"{curDir}/volumes/rabbitmq/plugins", "/myplugins")
            .WithArgs("rabbitmq-plugins", "enable", "rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange")
            ;



        builder.Build().Run();

When container starts, detect the plugin, but when execute 'rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange", try to reboot, and the container stops


How can I get RabbitMQ with plugin running?
Thanks
